# $\tan A =\frac{p}{q}$. Simplify $q \sin A \cos A + p \sin^2 A$.

Tags: trigonometry

Please help me solve this, maths test in a couple days and I am stumped by this question:

> $$\tan A = \frac{p}{q}. \;\text{Simplify}\; q \sin A \cos A + p \sin^2 A .$$

I get to defining $A$ for each part of the equation, but can't go any further. Someone please explain it to me!

Answer (score 2):

Well q sinA =p cosA and your expression is sinA (qsinA +pcosA ) .Take over soldier .

Comment: I agree with the first observation, but not with the second.  Please see my answer.

Comment: Sorry I got the q and p reversed , sin A (p sin A +q cos A) =...as you say =p  My factoring out the sin A was a red herring .Good job Barry  Cipra

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$q\sin A\cos A+p\sin^2A=\cos^2A\Bigl(\dfrac{q\sin A\cos A+p\sin^2A}{\cos^2A}\Bigr)=\cos^2A(q\tan A+p\tan^2A)=\dfrac{q\tan A+p\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}$.

Comment: If you note that $\tan A=p/q$ implies $q\tan A=p$, things simplify considerably!

Comment: @Barry Cipra: I posted only a (rather detailed) hint. There must remain some work for the O.P. :o)

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the boldface "Hint."  Sorry

Comment: Don't be sorry. The O.P. will be grateful – if he/she reads comments.

Answer (score 1):

If $\tan A=p/q$, then $q\sin A=p\cos A$, in which case

$$q\sin A\cos A+p\sin^2A=p\cos^2A+p\sin^2A=p(\cos^2A+\sin^2A)=p$$

Answer (score 1):

The diagram below represents a right triangle where $\tan A=\dfrac{p}{q}$.

For $A$ non-acute, a similar triangle can be drawn in any of the four quadrants with $A$ at the origin.

From the triangle we see that

$$ \sin A=\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}} $$

and

$$ \cos a=\frac{q}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}} $$

Thus

\begin{eqnarray}
q\sin A\cos A+p\sin^2A&=&q\cdot\frac{pq}{p^2+q^2}+p\cdot\frac{p^2}{p^2+q^2}\\
&=&p\cdot\frac{p^2+q^2}{p^2+q^2}\\
&=&p
\end{eqnarray}

[image: triangle]

Answer (score 0):

Since
$\sin(2a) = 2\sin(a)\cos(a)
$
and
$\cos(2a)
=\cos^2(a)-\sin^2(a)
=\cos^2(a)+\sin^2(a)-2\sin^2(a)
=1 - 2\sin^2(a)
$,
we have
$q\sin(a)\cos(a)+p\sin^2(a)
=q\sin(2a)/2+p(1-\cos(2a))/2
=(q\sin(2a)-p\cos(2a))/2+p/2
$.

Now use the fact that
you cn write
$u\sin(x)+v\cos()
=r\sin(x+s)
$
where
$r$ and $s$
can be specified
in terms of
$u$ and $v$.

Comment: I don't think it's this hard.  Please see my answer.

Comment: You are right. I ignored the equality.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

$$\tan{A}=\frac{p}{q}$$

$$\frac{sin{A}}{\cos{A}}=\frac{p}{q}$$

$$q\sin{A}=p\cos{A}$$

Through substitution:

$$q \sin A \cos A + p \sin^2 A$$

$$p\cos{A}\cos{A}+p\sin^{2}{A}$$

$$p\cos^{2}{A}+p\sin^{2}{A}$$

$$p\left(\cos^{2}{A}+\sin^{2}{A}\right)$$

But,

$$\left(\cos^{2}{A}+\sin^{2}{A}\right)=1$$

Then,

$$p\left(\cos^{2}{A}+\sin^{2}{A}\right)=p$$